# Issue with application.cfc showing message "Variable PRIMARYDATASOURCE is undefined" for datasource

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, application.cfc

When I try to fire simple select query in index.cfm, using a datasource defined in Application.cfc it shows an error message. Can anyone help me with proper code sequence?

**Error:**

> Variable PRIMARYDATASOURCE is undefined

**Application.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent>

    <!--- Set up the application. --->
    <cfscript>
        this.name = ""; // app name from old cfapplication tag
        this.sessionManagement = "Yes";
        this.loginstorage="session";
        this.setClientCookies = "Yes";
        this.primarydatasource = "diet";
        application.PRIMARYDATASOURCE = "diet";
    </cfscript>

    <cfsetting requesttimeout="100000" />

    <cffunction name="onApplicationStart">
            ....

        <cfquery datasource="#application.PRIMARYDATASOURCE#" name="getCostDetails">
            select * from maimun.adCostDetails ORDER BY ID DESC
        </cfquery>
            ....
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move line `application.PRIMARYDATASOURCE = "diet";` to the `onApplicationStart` function and remove line `this.primarydatasource = "diet";`. Done.

Code placed in the body of `Application.cfc` simply isn't executed the way you think it is. You can only access the `application` scope once the application has been initialized - and `onApplicationStart` is the event for that. Consider it as the constructor of your web application.

Comment: Though perhaps you meant to use [`this.datasource`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/application-cfc-reference/application-variables.html) ? That defines a default datasource for the application, allowing you to use cfquery *without* specifying the "datasource" attribute.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your Help, i missed that part, actually not having much knowledge about Application.cfc Thanks Leigh for this usefull information.